# string literals as template arguments forces code duplication and verbosity

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, consteval, constinit

A compile-time created string is being used as a character array in a structure and its max size is driven by that string. Also that structure is being used as a member variable in another struct, and there are multiple of such string buffer structs in it, which in turn drives its storage size.

Using strings as template arguments does work, but introduces multiple code repetitions, spreading like wild fire through the source code. Matters get even worse when the first structure has multiple strings as template arguments (2 or even 3).

Here's a working example:

```
#include <cstddef>

static constinit decltype(auto) c = "abc";
//static constinit decltype(auto) c2 = "12";

// size of A is driven by compile-time-created strings
template<typename T, size_t N /*, typename T2, size_t N2*/>
struct A{
    char str[N] {};
//    char str2[N2] {};

    consteval A(const T(&s)[N] /*, const T2(&s2)[N2]*/) {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
            str[i] = s[i];
            if(s[i] == 0) // for strings shorter than storage
                break;
        }
//        for(int i = 0; i < N2; ++i){
//            str2[i] = s2[i];
//            if(s2[i] == 0)
//                break;
//        }
    }
};

// dummy function which's sole purpose is to help with the type deduction
template<typename T, size_t N /*, typename T2, size_t N2*/>
consteval auto f(const T(&s)[N] /*, const T2(&s2)[N2]*/){
    return A<T, N /*, T2, N2*/>(s /*, s2*/);
}

// size of B's members and struct's total size are driven by compile-time
// created strings
struct B{
    // explicit (manual) error-prone template params
    A<char, 4 /*, char, 3*/>      xxx{c /*, c2*/};
    // use of a dummy function feels very wrong
    decltype(f(c /*, c2*/))       yyy{c /*, c2*/};
    // also uses dummy function
    decltype(f("abc" /*, "12"*/)) zzz{"abc" /*, "12"*/};
    // would like to be able to use shorter strings
  //A<char, 4 /*, char, 3*/>      fail{"a" /*, "1"*/};
};
```

The 3 working examples of usage are either prone to mistakes or introduce too much code repetition. And the last one, that is not working, is a nice-to-have sort of thing along the lines of "I wonder if this is doable?" to me.

[Link to Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5jKesj48Y)

Is there anything I'm missing in the C++ standard that would let me avoid repetition while retaining this automation to avoid potential manual mistakes?

Ideally I'd've loved to just code like this snippet below:

```
struct B{
    // automatic type deduction without some dummy function's help
    A xxx{c /*, c2*/};
    // strings in multiple TUs produce independent templates in current standard :(
    A<"abc" /*, c2*/> xxx;
};

// usage

// constructs with { {c /*, c2*/}, {"abc" /*, c2*/} }
constinit B b;

// constructs with { {c /*, c2*/}, {"bc" /*, "0"*/} }
constinit B b2{{}, {"bc" /*, "0"*/}};
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/r7nzPfabK)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to define size of variables in object solely by size of its **default** value? If this is supposed to be `const` objects I think it can be done in some other way... In all other cases you can use `auto x = f("abc");` As for code duplication problem, did you tried to use `std::string_view` instead of plain strings as templet argument?

Comment: By the way, automatic argument deduction  is explicitly disallowed in non-static struct members, so there will have to be _some_ repetition if you need the length as a compile-time constant.

Comment: As a [static member](https://godbolt.org/z/Exaf1PWY9), automatic argument deduction works fine.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I like what you've done, unfortunately your code suffers from the same kind of repetition (albeit in a different way)

Comment: @YePhIcK I would disagree that it's the "same kind" of repetition. At least in my case the source of truth is identical for both the type and the default value, so a refactor-rename (using F2 in some IDEs) would successfully change both occurences while that would not be true for the examples you provided, save for the cumbersome dummy function approach.

Comment: @sklott this is used in embedded code to generate USB descriptors which could get updated at run time based on USB connection speed (thus the need for potentially shorter strings)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree with what you said. And for this contrived simplified example it is not as evident that there's plenty of code repetition for a more complex case (I'm afraid it'd be too much code to show this easily). This is an example of a mess I'm trying to untangle: https://godbolt.org/z/x3c6bv93c

Comment: @YePhIcK why not just `struct S2rMsOs20RegPropGuid : decltype(A{c1, c2}) { using A::A; constexpr S2rMsOs20RegPropGuid() : A{c1, c2} {} };`? Problem solved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250948/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-yephick).

Answer (score 1):

Without using standard library headers (excepting `<cstddef>`), here's a definition for the class template `A` that gets most of the desired features with as little boilerplate as possible, given that C++ disallows automatic argument deduction in non-static struct member declarations. This uses a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides):

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct A {
  // + 1 to account for null termination in storage
  T str[N + 1];

  template <std::size_t... Ns>
  // to prevent aggregate construction from compiling
  // if sum of string literal sizes exceed storage capacity
    requires(N + 1 > (0 + ... + (Ns - 1)))
  consteval A(const T (&...s)[Ns]) {
    auto it = str;
    (..., [&](const auto &r) {
      for (const auto c : r) {
        if (!c) break;
        *it++ = c;
      }
    }(s));
    *it = T{};
  }
};

// user-defined deduction guide
template <typename T, std::size_t... Ns>
// - 1 to exclude null termination from each string literal in the pack
A(const T (&...s)[Ns]) -> A<T, (0 + ... + (Ns - 1))>;
```

Usage and tests below, with [obligatory Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/d64fxrTvd):

```cpp
static constinit decltype(auto) c1 = "abc";
static constinit decltype(auto) c2 = "12";

struct B {
  // no dummy function
  // but requires repetition of the compile-time constants
  // in the type expression
  decltype(A{c1, c2}) value{c1, c2};
};

#include <concepts>

// deduces correct width from compile-time constants
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(B{}.value), A<char, 5>>);

#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

// default construction
static_assert(B{}.value.str == "abc12"sv);
// aggregate construction
static_assert(B{{}}.value.str == ""sv);
static_assert(B{{c1}}.value.str == "abc"sv);
static_assert(B{{c2}}.value.str == "12"sv);
static_assert(B{{c2, c1}}.value.str == "12abc"sv);
static_assert(B{{"a", "1"}}.value.str == "a1"sv);
// candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with Ns = <3, 5>]
// because '5UL + 1 > 0 + (3UL - 1) + (5UL - 1)' (6 > 6) evaluated to false
// static_assert(B{{"ab", "1234"}}.value.str == "ab1234"sv);
```

---

To completely eliminate duplication in the declaration, you can create a derived class that behaves like `A{c1, c2}`. To make the linkage well-behaved, you'll need to canonicalize the template arguments of the derived class. Here's one way to do that:

```cpp
template <typename T, T... Cs>
struct C : decltype(A{{Cs..., T{}}}) {
  using base = decltype(A{{Cs..., T{}}});
  using base::base;

  constexpr C() : base{{Cs..., T{}}} {}
};

#include <utility>

template <A, typename...>
struct to_c;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, A<T, N> a>
struct to_c<a> : to_c<a, std::make_index_sequence<N>> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t N, A<T, N> a, std::size_t... Is>
struct to_c<a, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  using type = C<T, a.str[Is]...>;
};

template <A... a>
using to_c_t = typename to_c<A{a.str...}>::type;

static constinit decltype(auto) c1 = "abc";
static constinit decltype(auto) c2 = "12";

#include <concepts>

static_assert(std::same_as<to_c_t<c1, c2>, C<char, 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2'>>);
```

For your purposes, `to_c_t<c1, c2> value;` should behave almost like `decltype(A{c1, c2}) value{c1, c2};`, except there's no duplication, and it is safe to use across translation units since it is an alias for the canonical type `C<char, 'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2'>`. Just for completeness, here's [the full example using this approach](https://godbolt.org/z/zYM9KGvne).

Comment: thank you so much for your time and insights. Can't mark your answer as an answer though (besides the code bloat that is caused by the desire to reduce the code bloat in the first place it also does unwanted side effects, like concatenating all the input strings into one contiguous storage). Though as it is indeed a great answer I'm marking it as such. As an added benefit here's the "final" version of the truly generic library-grade code that came out of side discussion with @Patrick https://godbolt.org/z/nGxKxK4q7